# Prove that there is a unique probability on $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mathbb P([0,x])=x$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to define a probability space $([0,1],\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ where $\mathbb P([0,x])=x$.

I would like to prove that there is no probability measure on $2^{[0,1]}$, and that there is a unique probability on $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mathbb P([0,x])=x$, and for such a space $\mathcal F=\sigma (\{[0,x]\mid x\in [0,1])$. My teacher said that it's a hard exercise, but do you have a reference for such a proof ?

Comment: uniqueness lemma? If probability measures agree on the $\pi$-system $\{[0,x]\}$ then they agree on $\sigma(\{[0,x]\})$

Comment: Are you effectively asking two separate questions ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the sense of your question.

Comment: @user386627 Your first question is "Prove there is no probability measure on $2^{[0,1]}$" and the second is "there is a unique probability on $[0,1]$ s.t. ...", right ? You should create a separate post for each.